# diff two files based on part of lines

Tags: shell, sed, grep, diff

I have a file containing rows like

> 010203040506 azerty
>
> 020304050607 qwerty

and another file with rows like

> xxxxxxxxxxxxxx 010203040506 yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy

=> Files have millions of rows

=> How can I make something "like a diff" : get the first files rows but without the lines for which the number is in a line in the second file ?
Like in my example the result should be

> 020304050607 qwerty

Comment: 1. Use `sed`, to parse the second file - remove everything and  extract the column with numbers only. 2. `sort` both files on the first column, ie. the column with numbers. 3. Use `join` to join both files on the first column. Actually I see `sed` is not really needed, if the numbers are separated nicely by spaces as shown, you can just `sort` first file on first column, second file on second column. Then just `join` on `-11 -22` with `-o 1.1,1.2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to KamilCuk answer and this link https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Paired-and-unpaired-lines.html I found join -v 1 file1 file2 to show only unpaired lines